# How to get all resource record set for a particular hosted zone from route 53 using java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am using below code to get all records but it always return 100 record for a particular hosted zone. I want to display all the resource records for a hosted zone.

```
public List<ResourceRecordSet> getResourceRecordSet(String hostedZoneId) {
    AmazonRoute53Client route53Client = new AmazonRoute53Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY));
    ListResourceRecordSetsRequest request = new ListResourceRecordSetsRequest();
    request.setHostedZoneId(hostedZoneId);
    return route53Client.listResourceRecordSets(request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to paginate and store all values in some other collection.

```
public List<ResourceRecordSet> getResourceRecordSet(String hostedZoneId) {
  AmazonRoute53Client route53Client = new AmazonRoute53Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY));
  String nextRecordName = null;
  List<ResourceRecordSet> allRecords = new ArrayList<>();
  do  {
    ListResourceRecordSetsRequest request = new ListResourceRecordSetsRequest();
    request.setHostedZoneId(hostedZoneId);
    if (nextRecordName != null) {
      request = request.withStartRecordName(nextRecordName);
    }
    ListResourceRecordSetsResult currentRecords = route53Client.listResourceRecordSets(request);
    nextRecordName = currentRecords.getNextRecordName();

    allRecords.addAll(currentRecords.getResourceRecordSets());
  } while (nextRecordName != null);
  return allRecords;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [pagination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-pagination.html)

Comment: I have tried  a lot but couldn't make it work. This should be very easy for someone who works with aws route53 with java more often than me.Could you tell me how to do pagination